# Convert time duration to quarters

Tags: java, android, datetime

I need to calculate a time difference into Quarters,Weeks,Days,Hours and Seconds. I can't get the formula correct. The formulas below should return: 3 Quarters, 12 Weeks, 6 Days, 23 Hours and 59 Minutes. I am by no means a math wiz so any help would be great.

```
long difference = 31535872360L;/*A few seconds short of a year*/

long min =   (int) ((difference / (1000*60))%60);/*Returns 59 Minutes*/
long hours = (int) ((difference / (1000*60*60)) % 24);/*Returns 23 Hours*/
long days =  (int) ((difference / (1000*60*60*24)) % 7);/*Returns 0 Days*/
long weeks = (int) ( difference / (1000*60*60*24*7)% 12);/*Returns 4 Weeks*/
long quarters = (int) (((difference / (1000*60*60*24*7)%12)/3)+1);/*Returns 2 Quarters*/
```

Comment: how do you define a quarter? 30*3 days? or a number of weeks?

Comment: how many quaters are in 364 days? "*A few seconds short of a year*/" you know that not every year have same length?

Comment: Years are variable in length.  some are 365 and others are 366 days long.

Comment: @leonbloy I am looking to make 12 weeks = 1 quarter. In the code above it should be 3 quarters, 12 weeks, 6 days, 23 hours and 59 minutes

Comment: Actually the above is 4 q,4 w, 0 d, 23:57:52

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this way is more clean and less prone to errors:

```
private static final long MIN_MS = 1000 * 60;
private static final long HOUR_MS = MIN_MS * 60;
private static final long DAY_MS = HOUR_MS * 24;
private static final long WEEK_MS = DAY_MS * 7;
private static final long QUARTER_MS = WEEK_MS * 12;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    long msecs = 31535872360L;/*A few seconds short of a year*/
    long q = msecs / QUARTER_MS;
    msecs -= q * QUARTER_MS;
    long w = msecs / WEEK_MS;
    msecs -= w * WEEK_MS;
    long d = msecs / DAY_MS;
    msecs -= d * DAY_MS;
    long h = msecs / HOUR_MS;
    msecs -= h * HOUR_MS;
    long min = msecs / MIN_MS;
    msecs -= min * MIN_MS;
    long secs = msecs / 1000;
    System.out.printf("%d q,%d w, %d d, %d:%d:%d \n", q, w, d, h, min, secs);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your quarter formula should be

```
long quarters = (int) ((difference / (1000*60*60*24*7*12) % 4);
```

Comment: This works but returns a -3, how to I make it positive?

Comment: I think simply removing the `int` cast will work, but if not then just wrap it in `Math.abs()`: `Math.abs((difference / (1000*60*60*24*7*12) % 4)`

Comment: This also doesn't return a lower value if less time is passed to difference IE: passing the difference in milliseconds of June 5 2013 - Today still results in a value of -3

Comment: Math.abs() turns it to a positive # but calculating the difference between today and 1 month from today gives me 1 quarter

Comment: I think it should be a "/" instead of "%": `((difference / (1000*60*60*24*7*12) / 4)`

Comment: That returns 5 quarters. I have been trying to wrap my head around this for weeks with no luck.

Comment: I just did it on my calculator, using the difference you have in your code, I get 4.345, which Java would truncate to 4.  If you're getting 5, then your code is not the same as what I put here.  It being 4 instead of 3 is because you've defined a quarter as 12 weeks, which means that 4 quarters only gives you 336 days while there are 365 days in a year (usually).